# Design pattern for StateMachine Reduction

Tags: design-patterns

Let's say i have a rather complex state machine but i want to provide a Interface with simplifies it by combining some states into one.

My problem with the solution below is that I would have code duplication because of the two enums sharing some states which also exist in the Interface.

Can anybody give me a hint for a design pattern?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum State { state0, state1, state2, state3, state4, state5 };
enum SimpleState { simple_state0, // <-- Duplication
               simple_state1, // <-- Duplication
               simple_state2, // <-- Duplication
               simple_state3, // <-- Duplication
               stateSimple }; // < state4 or state5

class ComplexStateMachine
{
public:
    State s_;

    State getState()
    {
        return s_;
    };
};


class SimpleInterface
{
public:
    SimpleInterface(ComplexStateMachine* c)
    {
        this->complex_ = c;
    };

    SimpleState getSimpleState()
    {
        switch(this->complex_->getState())
        {
            case state0:
                return simple_state0;
            case state1:
                return simple_state1;
            case state2:
                return simple_state2;
            case state3:
                return simple_state3;
            case state4:
            case state5:
                return stateSimple;
        }

    };

private:
    ComplexStateMachine* complex_;
};

int main() {

// Generate complex state machine
ComplexStateMachine* csm = new ComplexStateMachine();
csm->s_ = state0;

// Generate simple interface
SimpleInterface si(csm);
si.getSimpleState(); // <-- Should now return the simplified state

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "simplification" is a mapping of one simple state to possibly multiple complex states. If there is a one to one mapping, there is no simplification but only duplication. In your simple :) example, there is more duplication so I don't see a need for making a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

If your simple state machine really would encapsulate more complex states, the benefit may be larger and the duplication would be smaller.

Also, if it helps, you may try to model your state machine as a with states, that in itself contain other state machines in order to hide complexity:

[image: Complex state]

Comment: I really would like to use a interface since the StateMachine itself really has meaning with hardware behind, so I don't want to change it but rather work with a facade or something else.

Comment: So just add it, do the analysis of the necessary methods in the facade and formulate it in terms of the using classes, so that you maybe even don't need the duplicate states. e.g. maybe a small interface like this:
bool HasFinished(); Value GetResult();
is enough